# Keeping Escape Characters in C#

Tags: c#, string, amazon-web-services, escaping

I may be completely doing this wrong, or overlooking something obvious but here it goes.  I am working with AWS CLI via C#.  I am trying to send a command to the command line to change the instance type of the EC2

I've tried different ways of handling this, starting the string with @, single quotes encapsulating double quotes, etc.  Here is what I currently have:

```
private static void resizeCurrentInstance(string instance)
        {
            string commands = "/C aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids " + instance;
            string response = getNewProcess(commands);

            JObject convertedResponse = JObject.Parse(response);
            int i = 0;
            string ReturnString = "";

            foreach (JObject item in convertedResponse["Reservations"])
            {
                if (item["Instances"][i]["InstanceType"].Value<string>().Contains(".large"))
                {
                    string sizeUpCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id" + instance + " --instance-type \"{\"Value\": \"m4.4xlarge\"}\"";
                    string sizeUpResponse = getNewProcess(sizeUpCommand);

                    Console.WriteLine("Instance Size inscrease " + sizeUpResponse.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    string sizeDownCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id " + instance + ' --instance-type \"{\"Value\": \"m4.large\"}\"';
                    string sizeDownResponse = getNewProcess(sizeDownCommand);

                    Console.WriteLine("Instance Size decrease " + sizeDownResponse.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem comes from trying to generate the command string to send to the command line here

```
string sizeUpCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id" + instance + " --instance-type \"{\"Value\": \"m4.4xlarge\"}\""
```

This is the command as its give in the amazon docs:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-1234567890abcdef0 --instance-type "{\"Value\": \"m1.small\"}"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a string so the **Output** is: "{\"Value\": \"m1.small\"}"

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How do I write the string so the output looks like this: "{\"Value\": \"m1.small\"}"  Sorry I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep a backslash in the string, then you use `\\` before the `\"`.

But you are also missing a space after `--instance-id`, which would mess up the command.

So it should look something like this:

```
string sizeUpCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id " + instance + " --instance-type \"{\\\"Value\\\": \\\"m4.4xlarge\\\"}\""
```

If that doesn't work, then output `sizeUpCommand` to the console and inspect it to make sure it is what it should be.

Comment: I tried this string sizeUpCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id" + instance + "--instance-type \"{\\\"Value\\\": \\\"m4.4xlarge\\\"}\""; and it failed to update

Comment: You're also missing a space after `--instance-id` and before `--instance-type`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"{\\\"Value\\\": \\\"m1.small\\\"}"
```

Comment: I tried this string sizeUpCommand = "/C aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id" + instance + "--instance-type \"{\\\"Value\\\": \\\"m4.4xlarge\\\"}\""; and it failed to update